# Blender2P3DFSX Question

Tags: installation

How do I uninstall Blender2P3DFSX0.98.21?  When I press the *N* key under Unknown add-ons with checkmark Blender2P3DFSX  Want to install version 0.98.34.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall an addon, navigate to either blender’s program files or its user data folder. In Windows, the user data would be in C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\… …\scripts\addons. Then, delete the addon’s files (usually a folder or just one Python script bearing its name).

For Mac users the folder is
/Macintosh HD/Users/(name)/Library/Application Support/Blender/(version)/scripts/addons